# How to get all possible combinations of a tuple (python)

Tags: python

I have a little bit of code that plots a cube in 3d space using coordinates from a tuple. I want to add faces to the cube by getting every possible combination of points and plotting all the triangles. Any idea how to do this, or is there a better way.

Anything helps,
thanks!

```
#the points I use to make the cube
points = [( 1,  1,  1), ( 1, -1,  1), 
          (-1, -1,  1), (-1,  1,  1), 
          ( 1,  1, -1), ( 1, -1, -1), 
          (-1, -1, -1), (-1,  1, -1)]
```

Comment: Obvious suggestion: you can use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: I might suggest instead [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) :) `L = [tpl for tpl in product((1, -1), repeat=3)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

def getAllCombos(my_list):
    return list(product(*((x, -x) for x in my_list)))
    
my_list = [1,1,1]

result = getAllCombos(my_list)

print(result)
```

This prints: `[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, -1, -1)]`